# jqGrid - filter not working

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

If i want to filter my columns, tip some letter into the search field and click '**search**' nothing happens.
My records are coming from a Mysql Database - all works fine, can see all of them correctly in my table - just the filtering doesn´t work for me.

What´s the problem i can´t see any mistake.

Here my codes:

(index.html)

```
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<style type="text/css">
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 75%;
}
</style>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-de.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "example.php",
    datatype: "xml",
    mtype: "GET",
    width:600,
    height: 'auto',
    colNames: ["ID", "kundenName", "kundenVorName", "kundenPLZ", "kundenOrt"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "id", width: 55 },
        { name: "kundenName", width: 90 },
        { name: "kundenVorName", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "kundenPLZ", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "kundenOrt", width: 80, align: "right" }

    ],
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: "id",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    caption: "My first grid"
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
        add: false,
        edit: false,
        del: false,
        search: true,
        refresh: true
});
}); 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
<div id="pager"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

and here the PHP file:

```
<?php 


$page = $_GET['page']; 

// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 

// connect to the MySQL database server 
$con = mysqli_connect("", "root", "") or die("Connection Error: "); 

// select the database 
mysqli_select_db($con,"kunden") or die("Error connecting to db."); 

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM personen"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 

// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
          $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
          $total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
$SQL = "SELECT id,kundenName,kundenVorName,kundenPLZ,kundenOrt FROM personen ORDER BY  $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($con)); 

// we should set the appropriate header information. Do not forget this.
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$s .=  "<rows>";
$s .= "<page>".$page."</page>";
$s .= "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";
$s .= "<records>".$count."</records>";

// be sure to put text data in CDATA
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$s .= "<row id='". $row['id']."'>";            
$s .= "<cell>". $row['id']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['kundenName']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['kundenVorName']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['kundenPLZ']."</cell>";
$s .= "<cell>". $row['kundenOrt']."</cell>";
$s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>"; 

echo $s;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any code for handling `searchField` and `searchString` anywhere in your php code. If you look at the request it should have search set to true and some searchField searchString which you need to handle in your code in order to properly filter the results a.k.a. include it in your db query. P.S.: Maybe `searchOper` too.